# Não consigo exibir a data de modificação de um diretório com o powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

Olá, estou tentando exibir a data de criação e de modificação de um diretório usando o powershell, estou usando o comando:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Directory -filter 'Drive="C:" and Path="\\"' -ComputerName MyPC |
select FileName,LastModified -First 3
```

porem o retorno que tenho é uma string:

```
FileName                         LastModified             
--------                         ------------             
$recycle.bin                     20151022091602.219458-120
0f74e86e50f02a5493eece53fbe1da58 20141005215102.861881-180
384d408957a87176de               20141004215102.325431-180
```

Como fazer exibir a data ou para converter essas string em data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a informação que queria formatando a saida gerada com o seguinte codigo:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Directory -filter 'Drive="D:" and Path="\\users\\"' -ComputerName $HostName | sort LastModified -Descending | select -First 3 | foreach{
   $newObj = "" | select Name,LastModified,hostname
   $newObj.Name = $_.Name
   $newObj.LastModified = $_.LastModified.Substring(0,8).Insert(4,"/").Insert(7,"/")
   $newObj.hostname = $HostName

   $newObj
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o Get-ItemProperty.
Ex:

`(Get-ItemProperty C:\Temp).CreationTime`
segunda-feira, 30 de março de 2015 20:15:55

`(Get-ItemProperty C:\Temp).LastWriteTime`
quinta-feira, 7 de janeiro de 2016 17:56:06

Comment: O comando não funciona quando eu quero pegar a informação de uma maquina remota. Para isso teria que usar invoke-comand, porem consegui formatar a saida para o padrão que eu queria.